# Why boostrap put type="button" in button tag

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

Why does bootstrap use 'type=button' when making a button? Is it redundant?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

Comment: `type="button"` prevents the browser for submitting a form. If you wish to submit a form use `submit` instead of `button`

Comment: No, it is not redundant. Look up what the default value for `type` is.

Comment: Please first google before asking such a question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is used to specify the default action of the button. The button type states that "it has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur." Normally, this is how a button would act by itself. However, a button is normally found within a form, where when clicked it automatically submits the form. By specifying type=button, it overrides this default behavior, so it would not submit. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button